# BAPI_SYSTEM_MT_GETALERTDATA, call using Java is returning only 10 recent alerts

Tags: java, sap-basis, bapi

`BAPI_SYSTEM_MT_GETALERTDATA` called using Java is returning only 10 recent alerts. I want to find all the alerts for a given range if dates. Please let me know how we can do it.

Comment: Please provide your work and references on this so far.

Comment: We are using BAPI calls to get the data from SAP into our system(Java). We are fetching the alerts from SAP system. For a given range of dates we are not able to retrieve more than 10 recent alters. The question is how can we get all the previous alerts also for the given range.

Comment: please post your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number 10 has nothing to do with `BAPI_SYSTEM_MT_GETALERTDATA` FM. This parameter is called **Maximum Number of Alerts Kept**, and it is adjusted in [CCMS alert monitoring settings](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/f1/33d03b55338733e10000000a11402f/content.htm), which is `S_B6A_52000011` transaction.

[image]

It seems that you simply have such setting on the remote system and this setting cannot be changed remotely. Alerts beyond 10 **are not stored** at all.

Comment: Thanks for the information, could you please let me know if there is anyway so that my system (JAVA) could fetch more than 10 records from SAP. For e.g. fetching from a table etc.

Comment: I don't think so. CCMS logs are stored not in tables but [in files](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nwpi711/helpdata/en/49/8ba8e5e0a73eeee10000000a421937/content.htm), however they are useless, 'cause logs more than 10 won't be recorded at all.